# Determine if a file has been modified

Tags: files, timestamps, stat

In Linux (currently using ext4 filesystem), how can one check quickly if the contents of a file has been modified *without* reading any of its contents?

Is the `stat` command a recommended approach? I currently do

```
$ stat --format "%Y" hello.txt
```

and later I can check if the same command yields the same output. If it does, I conclude that hello.txt has not changed.

My feeling is that one wants to throw in more parameters to be even more sure. For example, would adding the file size, file name, etc, provide an even better "fingerprint" of the file?

On this topic, I recall that a TrueCrypt volume I once had was always ignored by my incremental backup program, possibly because TrueCrypt made sure to leave no meta data changes behind. I suppose it is indeed possible to change all the data returned by `stat`, hence it cannot be guaranteed to pick up on every possible modification of the file?

Comment: `md5sum filename`?

Comment: `md5sum` or any sort of checksum reads the contents of the file. I do not want to do that as it is way too slow for my purposes.

Comment: `ls -t` will sort the contents in a directory by modification time.

Comment: "has been modified"?  Every file has been modified, the question is *when* was it modified. You can use 'find' to search for a specific range of modification times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to detect whether a file has been modified through normal means (editing it in some application, checking out a new version from a revision control systems, rebuilding it, etc.), check whether its modification time (mtime) has changed from the last check. That's what `stat -c %Y` reports.

The modification time can be set by the `touch` command. If you want to detect whether the file has changed in any way (including the use of `touch`, extracting an archive, etc.), check whether its inode change time (**ctime**) has changed from the last check. That's what `stat -c %Z` reports. The ctime cannot be spoofed except by the system administrator (and even then, only through indirect means: by changing the system clock, or by accessing the disk directly, bypassing the filesystem).

Comment: Thanks, I gather that ctime is what I should use. It did not follow from my question that the purpose of this is to use it in my own backup script, where checksums will be computed only for new files or files that have changed. I can afford computing checksums for files that have changed just "slightly", say permissions have changed, etc. I prefer being as close as possible to actually looking at the contents of the file to determine a change.

Answer (score 3):

The stat command only has a resolution of a second.  So if the file was modified twice in the same second you could miss a modification.  Newer filesystems like ext4 provide higher resolution timestamps in nanoseconds, but some of the old tools haven't caught up yet.

Also, it's possible for other programs to set an arbitrary modification time. You can see how this can happen via the touch command.

If you're concerned about either of those two possibilities it wouldn't be a bad idea to look at the file size as well.  This is what rsync does when it's looking for modified files.

Answer (score 2):

> My feeling is that one wants to throw in more parameters to be even more sure.

What you have is the correct method.  The only reason for that to fail would be if the filesystem is not updating properly -- in which case you will end up with a whole bunch of more serious problems.

Of course, I presume someone with the right knowledge and root access to a system where the partition is accessible might be able to alter the information to make it *look* as if the file hasn't been changed.  However, in this case they would surely have made sure to do the same with the size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I make the fingerprint more detailed.

I made a little wrapper function that generates identical output for both the MacOS/BSD and GNU versions of `stat` (also detects the Homebrew-installed version with a `g` prefix).

```
init() {
  if command -v gstat > /dev/null; then
    # GNU coreutils with g prefix.
    statCmdArgs=("gstat" "--format=%n %s %b %u %g %i %h %Y %Z %W %o");
  elif ! stat --version > /dev/null 2> /dev/null; then
    # MacOS/BSD stat
    statCmdArgs=("stat" "-f" "%N %z %b %u %g %i %l %m %c %B %k");
  else
    # Assume GNU version without prefix.
    statCmdArgs=("stat" "--format=%n %s %b %u %g %i %h %Y %Z %W %o");
  fi;
}

getFileStatus() {
  "${statCmdArgs[@]}" "$1";
}
```

The `init` function gets called once during script initialization and `getFileStatus` can be called repeatedly without the detection overhead.